# Http Simple server error 404 with requests.get but success when wget

Tags: python, http, ubuntu, server

I have set up a HTTP simple server to host my files.

I am getting status code of 404 when i run the following function in my code

```
response = requests.get(url)
code = response.status_code
```

However, when using wget to fetch the file, it works

```
wget --no-proxy <url>
```

Anyone know what happens here? Appreciate if any advise

> URL = http://localhost:8000/sample.tar
>
> **Python code and `wget` command ran in same machine

Code snippet:

```
def get(url):


    if url == '':
        raise ValueError('Empty Fetch URL')

    try:
        logging.debug('Attempting to get ' + url)
        response = requests.get(url)

        code = response.status_code
        logging.debug('Status code for ' + url + ' is ' + str(code))
        message = http.client.responses[code]

        response.raise_for_status()

    except (requests.exceptions.InvalidURL, requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema):
        custom = http.client.responses[code]
        logging.error('%d %s', code, custom)
        return dict(status=code, message=custom)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        logging.error('%d %s', code, message)
        return dict(status=code, message=message)

    logging.info('%d %s', code, message)
    return dict(status=code, message=message)

###main###
URL = "http://localhost:8000/sample.tar"
get(URL)
```

Comment: You are using `--no-proxy` in wget. Have you tried the python code after unsetting the proxies?

Comment: @BishakhGhosh Hi, just tried out wget without `no-proxy` flag, it works too.

Comment: I have set both http_proxy and no_proxy in environment setting, so high possibilities this is not proxy issue ??

Comment: can you please post the whole code (including the url part)

Comment: @BishakhGhosh updated code snippet in question

Comment: Do you have access to the server log files? If so, what do they say about the unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: @DyZ Hi, this is a python SimpleHTTPServer which hosted in my own machine and pointed to a working directory that keeping my files. How should I get the server log files? So far the only log i able to check is by running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`